# Find out which ending is the most common in a language

Tags: bash, script, text-editing, tld

I would like to work out what the most useful TLDs are for [domain hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_hack)
(i.e., creating short FQDNs that spell words by combining with a TLD,
e.g., `ho.me`) in English.

Here is a list of public suffixes https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat,
which I'd like to check against words in the English language
to see which are most popular.

How can I achieve this, e.g., using a script?

Comment: Fair enough. I decided to answer it myself with a quick bash script. Feel free to close in any case - I appreciate that it is off topic.

Comment: This might be more suitable on [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes - I thought the same, but wondered if it was too easy. Feel free to move there if appropriate.

Comment: I guess if the question could be slightly re-worded it could stay here, say, you already have an input list, and you're looking for a way to analyze it using a script … that's the kind of question we get often.

Comment: OK - I've edited it a bit.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing a little bit, assuming you were using Bash. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

This bash script works, using a list of tlds from https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

`for TLD in $(grep -E '^[a-z]+$' public_suffix_list.dat); do echo $(grep $TLD /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l) $TLD; done | grep -v ^0 | sort -nr`

Top 10 are:

```
16147 in
13129 es
9573 ng
9276 re
9174 at
8625 st
8331 ing
7383 ar
6762 li
6469 al
```

See https://gist.github.com/michaelmcandrew/a7de275eb57053206a17c6e9316ea86a for a full list.

Comment: What is ```.ing```? It's not a top-level domain.